# Java Error being thrown

Tags: java, database

I'm new to Java and have been working through the tutorial on databases on this site.
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/move_to_the_first_and_last_records.html

Using Netbeans it's giving me the error output of

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Employees.Workers.btnNextActionPerformed(Workers.java:231)
at Employees.Workers.access$200(Workers.java:19)
at Employees.Workers$3.actionPerformed(Workers.java:140)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This code runs fine and loads the first set of details in the database into the text boxes as expected.

```
public Workers() {
    initComponents();
    DoConnect();
}

public void DoConnect( ) {

    try{
        String strHost = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String strUsername = "";
        String strPassword = "";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(strHost, strUsername, strPassword);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSQL);

        rs.next();
        int nId = rs.getInt("ID");
        String strId = Integer.toString(nId);
        String strFirstName = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String strLastName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String strJobTitle = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textBoxId.setText(strId);
        textBoxFirstName.setText(strFirstName);
        textBoxLastName.setText(strLastName);
        textBoxJobTitle.setText(strJobTitle);

    }
    catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The code throwing the errors are the button presses and they all give me the same error.

```
    private void btnFirstActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        rs.first();
        int nId = rs.getInt("ID");
        String strId = Integer.toString(nId);
        String strFirstName = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String strLastName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String strJobTitle = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textBoxId.setText(strId);
        textBoxFirstName.setText(strFirstName);
        textBoxLastName.setText(strLastName);
        textBoxJobTitle.setText(strJobTitle);
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}                                        

private void btnPreviousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        if (rs.previous()) {
            int nId = rs.getInt("ID");
            String strId = Integer.toString(nId);
            String strFirstName = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String strLastName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String strJobTitle = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            textBoxId.setText(strId);
            textBoxFirstName.setText(strFirstName);
            textBoxLastName.setText(strLastName);
            textBoxJobTitle.setText(strJobTitle);
        }
        else {
            rs.next();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "End of File");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}                                           

private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            int nId = rs.getInt("ID");
            String strId = Integer.toString(nId);
            String strFirstName = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String strLastName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String strJobTitle = rs.getString("Job_Title");

            textBoxId.setText(strId);
            textBoxFirstName.setText(strFirstName);
            textBoxLastName.setText(strLastName);
            textBoxJobTitle.setText(strJobTitle);
        }
        else {
            rs.previous();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "End of File");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}                                       

private void btnLastActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        rs.last();
        int nId = rs.getInt("ID");
        String strId = Integer.toString(nId);
        String strFirstName = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String strLastName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String strJobTitle = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        textBoxId.setText(strId);
        textBoxFirstName.setText(strFirstName);
        textBoxLastName.setText(strLastName);
        textBoxJobTitle.setText(strJobTitle);
    }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I don't think it's the database code itself. I use the same code to preload the first entry into some text boxes and it works fine for that.
Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: what line exactly is line 231? it should be some place in the btnPreviousActionPerformed function

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: i suspect this line - String strId = Integer.toString(nId);

Comment: RAZ_Muh_Taz Line 231 is if (rs.next()) {

Comment: Probably `rs` is `null`. Where did you define it ?

Comment: The Head Rush Assuming you're talking about int nId it runs fine when use it to add the first set of details from the database in the constructor using the exact same code.

Comment: PeterMmm, I've added the code to the original post.

Comment: You have `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSQL);` in `DoConnect()`, but this is a method local reference. Probably you won't `ResultSet` in that line, because you have a instance variable in the `Worker` class with the same name, but you don't show that code.